# Kong ingress not working with OPTIONS call, throwing CORS error

Tags: spring-boot, cors, kong, kong-ingress

I am new to Kong, I am using the CORS plugin of the Kong.
I did all configuration correctly in my `kong.yml` file. My endpoint is deployed successfully and I can hit it through postman as well.
But when React UI calls my endpoint on Submit button click I am getting CORS error of preflight as my react code is on different domain.
I am using Google Cloud Platform as cloud service provider.

Following is my `plugins.yaml` file which enables the Kong CORS plugin.

```yaml
plugins:
- name: cors
  service: my-service-name
  protocols: 
     - grpc
     - grpcs
     - http
     - https
  config:
    origins:
      - '*'
    headers:
      - Origin
      - Authorization
      - X-Requested-With
      - Content-Type
    methods:
      - GET
      - PUT
      - PATCH
      - POST
      - DELETE
      - OPTIONS
    max_age: 3600
    credentials: true
    preflight_continue: true
  enabled: true
```

I tried making preflight_continue flag true and false, tried adding different headers, but no luck.

I am getting below error (following are debugging details):

> Access to XMLHttpReques at 'https://my_Kong_url' from origin 'https://my_react_server' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> POst 'https://my_kong_url' net::ERR_FAILED

Client code is in React framework:

```
fetch(<url>, <body>)
```

Comment: Show the client code.

Comment: How's Kong's Route configured? Are you setting them with `paths`  or using `hosts`?

Comment: @Ponsakorn30214 - I searched a lot on setting the paths and hosts, could not get example, can you please help me with that.

Comment: @user7078 when creating Route object in Kong you can specify whether to use `paths` or `hosts` to route the request. If setting `hosts` value, you need to pass `Host` header to kong to hit that route. CORS plugin has a limitation on browsers doing OPTIONS requests to Kong with a custom Host header.

Comment: Hi @Ponsakorn30214 - can I add paths in above yaml which I have given in the question ? Or there is something else I need to update ?

Comment: Any ready solution @Ponsakorn30214 ?